# Get user photo by graph API - started getting "forbidden by policy"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API to get user photos. I started receiving 403 error with "ForbiddenByPolicy".

This call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userid>/photo/$value
```

Returns now:

```
{
    "code": "ForbiddenByPolicy",
    "message": "invalid_role",
    "innerError": {
       ....
    }
}
```

Note that the call below still succeeds and returns user info:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userid>
```

Until recently, the "photo" call was also working fine. It is still working fine for myself (but not for other users). Is this a new change in Graph API? Is this a new bug in Graph API?

The consent is given for the "User.Read" and "User.BasicRead.All" scopes.

--- the inner error

```
{
    "date": "2023-08-14T09:06:26",
    "request-id": "40ed6973-e474-4bfa-872e-5cd5aa55d513",
    "client-request-id": "40ed6973-e474-4bfa-872e-5cd5aa55d513"
}
```

Another example (graph explorer)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<somemail>/photo/$value
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ForbiddenByPolicy",
        "message": "invalid_role",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-08-14T09:10:08",
            "request-id": "2552817c-471f-412b-9768-bafd2d5bd437",
            "client-request-id": "53131fc3-c103-9f2e-f5ec-7afa217dbf7d"
        }
    }
}
```

Decoded token (to make sure the "User.BasicRead.All" present:

```
{
  "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/e2eaf3b1-beaf-47c8-aebd-9ed8150e1671/",
  "iat": 1693391362,
  "nbf": 1693391362,
  "exp": 1693478062,
  "acct": 0,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "AVQAq/8UAAAA1MIZNHNfR80E6+9zD4ufcmxQJq9szF5kKTaUqYE9Grp415NSwIu8N6cUoKBt7YwAlacVWbAGujJVQ8fmD2xmbe7X0UXw/a9LpSKmWG/KDJw=",
  "amr": [
    "pwd",
    "mfa"
  ],
  "app_displayname": "Graph Explorer",
  "appid": "de8bc8b5-d9f9-48b1-a8ad-b748da725064",
  "appidacr": "0",
  "family_name": "***",
  "given_name": "***",
  "idtyp": "user",
  "ipaddr": "*****",
  "name": "******",
  "oid": "f551a47b-7265-4e25-a3e6-2b933b899cf6",
  "platf": "3",
  "puid": "1003200094407824",
  "rh": "0.ASEAsfPq4q--yEeuvZ7YFQ4WcQMAAAAAAAAAwAAAAAAAAAAhAI8.",
  "scp": "Calendars.Read Channel.ReadBasic.All DelegatedPermissionGrant.ReadWrite.All email Files.Read GroupMember.Read.All openid profile Tasks.ReadWrite Team.ReadBasic.All TeamSettings.Read.All User.Read User.ReadBasic.All",
  "signin_state": [
    "kmsi"
  ],
  "sub": "2pAn2I8jpIxyOsihr29VT51reFEl4n58Q4QbHciuv4A",
  "tenant_region_scope": "EU",
  "tid": "e2eaf3b1-beaf-47c8-aebd-9ed8150e1671",
  "unique_name": "*****",
  "upn": "******",
  "uti": "FXN4CMLDXEiyMnxqsqVgAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "wids": [
    "11648597-926c-4cf3-9c36-bcebb0ba8dcc",
    "f2ef992c-3afb-46b9-b7cf-a126ee74c451",
    "69091246-20e8-4a56-aa4d-066075b2a7a8",
    "9b895d92-2cd3-44c7-9d02-a6ac2d5ea5c3",
    "75941009-915a-4869-abe7-691bff18279e",
    "f28a1f50-f6e7-4571-818b-6a12f2af6b6c",
    "cf1c38e5-3621-4004-a7cb-879624dced7c",
    "a9ea8996-122f-4c74-9520-8edcd192826c",
    "baf37b3a-610e-45da-9e62-d9d1e5e8914b",
    "b79fbf4d-3ef9-4689-8143-76b194e85509"
  ],
  "xms_cc": [
    "CP1"
  ],
  "xms_ssm": "1",
  "xms_st": {
    "sub": "SB91M9_xYO6hFj5HnPTKFP5P04-mXneD0fmsFl59Ulo"
  },
  "xms_tcdt": 1478011165,
  "xms_tdbr": "EU"
}
```

Comment: Do you use application or delegated permissions?

Comment: @user2250152 I am using delegated permissions.

Comment: I figured out the same. Some time ago users could receive their photo, but now not anymore. It seems that something changed. My token contains User.Read delegated permission, but still access denied. Help!

Comment: @DavidMason For me, it is only SOME users get this issue. For others it works like before. BTW, I think the scope that allows photo access, is "User.BasicRead.All" not "User.Read". The user.read is about the user himself.

Comment: share the inner error details including request id and timestamp

Comment: @Danstan executed the tre request just now and added the details

Comment: @Danstan did the request id or timestamp help?

Comment: been wondering what's the matter for few days, turns out I'm not the only one affected by this!

Comment: @DavidMason it looks like the issue with graph API not returning pictures was resolved today by Microsoft. Could you please recheck if it started working for you too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed by Microsoft (for me, it just started working again 19.09.2023).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After changing the profile picture of the affected account via the unified "Me" icon on the top right corner, things started to work again. Not sure if that's the root cause, MS might have also changed the graph internals...

Comment: The user can see own picture, this issue is about graph api, and other users' pictures. Meanwhile, I got a response from MS support: "This is regarding the update on the case. I have escalated the issue to our product group and would like to inform that it has been resolved identified as a bug. Our team is working on the fix. I will keep you posted on ETA of the resolution."

Answer (score -1):

From the request ID and timestamp details shared, the scopes in this token are as follows:

```
scp: "Calendars.Read Channel.ReadBasic.All DelegatedPermissionGrant.ReadWrite.All email Files.Read GroupMember.Read.All openid profile Tasks.ReadWrite Team.ReadBasic.All TeamSettings.Read.All User.Read"
```

Please ensure that the user has *User.ReadBasic.All* which allows to read properties of other users.
403 errors can arise from lack of permissions, lack of consent or poorly configured permission scopes.

Comment: I had already a support call with Microsoft, they said the request is elevated to second level of support. The scope is 100% not the problem, I showed it online in the graph explorer, where only 3 scopes were preset. The scopes you list are not the ones that are in that token, probably some mistake? The "User.ReadBasic.All" is definietely there, I mean; otherwise the request for /users/{userid} won't work.

Comment: Just in case, I shared more request samples with the support (for graph explorer, not for our app). Will add decoded token to the description to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Added the token to the description. As you can see, the "User.ReadBasic.All" is there. Another note, when a scope is missing, the error is different (NOT "forbidden by policy", but "consent required").